# I am making hangman in python and I am getting a weird print after everytime i enter a letter guess

Tags: python

when I run this code it works except I can only get wrong guesses and after every hangman, it just prints none can someone explain what is going wrong? I dont know how to fix it but i have done lots of googling and video watching and i have no idea what is going on i dont need someone to rewrite my whole code just someone to tell me where the issue is and possible fixes for it

```
import random
file1 = open("Words.txt")


def get_word():
    word = random.choice("Words.txt")
    return word.lower()


def play(word):
    word_completion = "_" * len(word)
    guessed = False
    guessed_letters = []
    guessed_words = []
    tries = 6
    print("Let's play Hangman!")
    print(draw_hangman(tries))
    print(word_completion)
    print("\n")
    while not guessed and tries > 0:
        guess = input("Please guess a letter or word: ").lower()
        if len(guess) == 1 and guess.isalpha():
            if guess in guessed_letters:
                print("You already guessed the letter", guess)
            elif guess not in word:
                print(guess, "is not in the word.")
                tries -= 1
                guessed_letters.append(guess)
            else:
                print("Good job,", guess, "is in the word!")
                guessed_letters.append(guess)
                word_as_list = list(word_completion)
                indices = [i for i, letter in enumerate(word) if letter == guess]
                for index in indices:
                    word_as_list[index] = guess
                word_completion = "".join(word_as_list)
                if "_" not in word_completion:
                    guessed = True
        elif len(guess) == len(word) and guess.isalpha():
            if guess in guessed_words:
                print("You already guessed the word", guess)
            elif guess != word:
                print(guess, "is not the word.")
                tries -= 1
                guessed_words.append(guess)
            else:
                guessed = True
                word_completion = word
        else:
            print("Not a valid guess.")
        print(draw_hangman(tries))
        print(word_completion)
        print("\n")
    if guessed:
        print("Congrats, you guessed the word! You win!")
    else:
        print("Sorry, you ran out of tries. The word was " + word + ". Maybe next time!")


def draw_hang_loser():
    print(" _________     \n")
    print("|         |    \n")
    print("|         0    \n")
    print("|        /|\   \n")
    print("|        / \   \n")
    print("|              \n")
    print("|              \n")


def draw_hang_head_body_legs_la():
    print(" _________     \n")
    print("|         |    \n")
    print("|         0    \n")
    print("|         |\   \n")
    print("|        / \   \n")
    print("|              \n")
    print("|              \n")


def draw_hang_head_body_legs():
    print(" _________     \n")
    print("|         |    \n")
    print("|         0    \n")
    print("|         |    \n")
    print("|        / \   \n")
    print("|              \n")
    print("|              \n")


def draw_hang_head_body_ll():
    print(" _________     \n")
    print("|         |    \n")
    print("|         0    \n")
    print("|         |    \n")
    print("|          \   \n")
    print("|              \n")
    print("|              \n")


def draw_hang_head_body():
    print(" _________     \n")
    print("|         |    \n")
    print("|         0    \n")
    print("|         |    \n")
    print("|              \n")
    print("|              \n")
    print("|              \n")


def draw_hang_head():
    print(" _________     \n")
    print("|         |    \n")
    print("|         0    \n")
    print("|              \n")
    print("|              \n")
    print("|              \n")
    print("|              \n")


def draw_hang_scaffold():
    print(" _________     \n")
    print("|         |    \n")
    print("|              \n")
    print("|              \n")
    print("|              \n")
    print("|              \n")
    print("|              \n")


def draw_hangman(state):
    if state == 0:
        draw_hang_scaffold()
    elif state == 1:
        draw_hang_head()
    elif state == 2:
        draw_hang_head_body()
    elif state == 3:
        draw_hang_head_body_ll()
    elif state == 4:
        draw_hang_head_body_legs()
    elif state == 5:
        draw_hang_head_body_legs_la()
    elif state == 6:
        draw_hang_loser()


def replace_all(orig, working, ch):
    done = False
    count = 0
    while not done:
        idx = orig.find(ch)
        if idx != -1:
            count = count + 1
            orig = orig[:idx] + "_" + orig[idx + 1:]
            working = working[:idx] + ch + working[idx + 1:]
        else:
            done = True
    return count != 0, orig, working


def main():
    word = get_word()
    play(word)
    while input("Play Again? (Y/N) ").upper() == "Y":
        word = get_word()
        play(word)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: "i have done lots of googling and video watching and i have no idea what is going on" Searching the Internet can only help you if you have something *specific* to search for. Right now, you don't *understand* the problem. You have to address that first, before you can do research. This means you need to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code. Try to work through the logic of the code and *look for* a *specific* thing that happens counter to your expectation.

Comment: Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow :)